# Should I patch or run PSCONFIG on the farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, patching, health-analyzer, psconfig

I am facing some issues with one of the farms, in particular the sandbox which consists of 2 WFE, 1 App Server and 1 DB server. In the image below you can see the Health Analyzer complaints for missing updates as well as for PSCONFIG.

[image]

I have no prior experience with patching a farm and I would like to ask where should I begin?

Should I patch first using the CU of October and then run PSCONFIG OR run PSCONFIG first patch and re-run PSCONFIG? In addition, what about the Windows Updates, are they included in the CU?

The error in detailed view:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run as Administrator "**SharePoint 2013 Management Shell**" and try:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Based on your experience, should I backup the farm before running this command?

Comment: For your own comfort it is always better to backup.

Answer (score 1):

Run SharePoint 2013 products configuration wizard in all SharePoint servers.

Or you can run the following PowerShell on all SharePoint servers:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources
```

You don't need to backup the farm before running this command.